# Create a nested route with a dynamic segment in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, emblem.js

I have a nested edit route for one of my resources:

```
@resource 'organization', path: 'organizations/:organization_id', ->
  @resource 'organization.edit', path: '/edit'
```

I link to it like this (using Emblem.js):

```
linkTo 'organization.edit' organization | Edit
```

Unfortunately, this results in a url like:

```
/organizations/4#
```

Rather than the expected:

```
/organizations/4/edit
```

Any idea why this is happening? I experimented with the route syntax a lot. Removing `path` for `organization.edit` does nothing, as does a full `path: 'organization/:organization_id/edit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get your desired result by using this type of nesting structure:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("organizations", function(){
    this.resource("organization", { path: "/:organization_id" }, function(){
      this.route("edit");
    });
  });
});
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1425/edit)

Comment: Your JSBin does the trick. Actually, I don't even have to nest the outer-most `organizations`. My mistake was using the syntax `linkTo 'organization.edit' organization` rather than `linkTo 'organization.edit' this`. Reading through your JSBin code revealed my error. Thanks for typing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but `@resource` is really intended for objects, e.g. organizations. If you're defining an action (not nested resources) you'll want to use `@route`, i.e.:

```
@resource 'organization', path: 'organizations/:organization_id', ->
  @route 'edit'
```

I believe that should give you the expected behaviour / routing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, the problem persists with this setup. If you have any other ideas, please send them my way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this:

```
@resource 'organization', ->
  @route "edit",
    path: "/:organization_id/edit"
```